# How to use js file within view folder

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I am using ruby on rails and I would like to render a partial on click (using jquery)  an example of this being:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){  
  $('#lol').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'myPartial' ) %>");
}
```

I basically want to submit a form then show the results (render partial) after in a read only format without the page refreshing. Problem is I can't use render in the asset pipeline. How do I include my JavaScript file from the view folder or what would be a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){  
 $('#lol').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'myPartial' ) %>");
}
```

*I think you are confusing between **ajax** and normal **jquery***. If you don't need to perform anything else then you should use normal jquery to show and hide your content. For that you need to put this code in your app/assets/javascript/application.js or make a new file then require it inside application.js like

```
//= require file_name
```

Inside your view you can hide the parent element of your content by giving it a style like this:

```
#your_content_container{
  display: none;
}
```

Then place your jquery code in your_file.js

```
$(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
  $("##your_content_container").show();
})
```

---

*If it's a form as your question says then you need to to perform some logic in your controller too so you should use **Ajax***

Since it's a form so you need to use **remote: true** option in your form something like:

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
  // your fields
<% end %>
```

and then inside your controller you can have

```
def your_method
  #do your logic here
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
  end
end
```

This will allow rails to look for a file named your_method.js.erb in your views where you can call your jquery and render your partial. In your_method.js.erb

```
$('#lol').append("<%=j render :partial => 'myPartial' %>");
```

For details refer to [**`Working with Javascript in Rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)